# On beacon Detected ALT BEACON

Tags: android, altbeacon

I can see a log in my consolse everytime a beacon is detected

**D/BeaconService: beacon detected : id1: xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx id2: xxx id3: xx**

But i could not figure out how to catch this function.
Which interface is needed for get this function.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show your code

Comment: I just copied the codes from this tutorials: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    // Y positions are relative to height of bg_distance image.
    Private static final double RELATIVE_START_POS = 320.0 / 1110.0;
    Private static final double RELATIVE_STOP_POS = 885.0 / 1110.0;

    Private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    Private Beacon beacon;
    Private Region region;
    Private View distance view, dotView;
    Private int startY = -1;
    Private int segmentLength = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.distance_view);
        dotView = findViewById(R.id.distance_iv_dot);
        beacon = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.EXTRAS_BEACON);
        region = new Region("regionid", beacon.getProximityUUID(), beacon.getMajor(), beacon.getMinor());
        if (beacon == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Beacon not found in intent extras", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        distanceview = findViewById(R.id.distance_background_view);
        distanceview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                distanceview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                startY = (int) (RELATIVE_START_POS * distanceview.getMeasuredHeight());
                int stopY = (int) (RELATIVE_STOP_POS * distanceview.getMeasuredHeight());
                segmentLength = stopY - startY;

                dotView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                dotView.setTranslationY(computeDotPosY(beacon));
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateDistanceView(Beacon foundBeacon) {
        if (segmentLength == -1) {
            return ;
        }

        dotView.animate().translationY(computeDotPosY(foundBeacon)).start();
    }

    private int computeDotPosY(Beacon beacon) {
        // Let's put dot at the end of the scale when it's further than 6m.
        double distance = Math.min(Utils.computeAccuracy(beacon), 6.0);
        return startY + (int) (segmentLength * (distance / 6.0));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> rangedBeacons) {
                // Note that results are not delivered on UI thread.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Just in case if there are multiple beacons with the same uuid, major, minor.
                        Beacon foundBeacon = null;
                        for (Beacon rangedBeacon : rangedBeacons) {
                            if (rangedBeacon.getMacAddress().equals(beacon.getMacAddress())) {
                                foundBeacon = rangedBeacon;
                            }
                        }
                        if (foundBeacon != null) {
                            updateDistanceView(foundBeacon);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                beaconManager.startRanging(region);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        beaconManager.stopRanging(region);
        beaconManager.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    } }
```

Write
Translate
Define
Synonyms
Favorites
Personal Trainer
Phrase of the Day
Personal Dictionary
Quick Tour
Tutorials
Settings
Send Feedback
GingerFREE

```
Public class DistanceBeaconActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Private static final String TAG = DistanceBeaconActivity. class. getSimpleName ();

    // Y positions are relative to height of bg_distance image.
    Private static final double RELATIVE_START_POS = 320.0 / 1110.0;
    Private static final double RELATIVE_STOP_POS = 885.0 / 1110.0;

    Private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    Private Beacon beacon;
    Private Region region;
    Private View distance view, dotView;
    Private int startY = -1;
    Private int segmentLength = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.distance_view);
        dotView = findViewById(R.id.distance_iv_dot);
        beacon = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.EXTRAS_BEACON);
        region = new Region("regionid", beacon.getProximityUUID(), beacon.getMajor(), beacon.getMinor());
        if (beacon == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Beacon not found in intent extras", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        distanceview = findViewById(R.id.distance_background_view);
        distanceview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                distanceview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                startY = (int) (RELATIVE_START_POS * distanceview.getMeasuredHeight());
                int stopY = (int) (RELATIVE_STOP_POS * distanceview.getMeasuredHeight());
                segmentLength = stopY - startY;

                dotView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                dotView.setTranslationY(computeDotPosY(beacon));
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateDistanceView(Beacon foundBeacon) {
        if (segmentLength == -1) {
            return ;
        }

        dotView.animate().translationY(computeDotPosY(foundBeacon)).start();
    }

    private int computeDotPosY(Beacon beacon) {
        // Let's put dot at the end of the scale when it's further than 6m.
        double distance = Math.min(Utils.computeAccuracy(beacon), 6.0);
        return startY + (int) (segmentLength * (distance / 6.0));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> rangedBeacons) {
                // Note that results are not delivered on UI thread.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Just in case if there are multiple beacons with the same uuid, major, minor.
                        Beacon foundBeacon = null;
                        for (Beacon rangedBeacon : rangedBeacons) {
                            if (rangedBeacon.getMacAddress().equals(beacon.getMacAddress())) {
                                foundBeacon = rangedBeacon;
                            }
                        }
                        if (foundBeacon != null) {
                            updateDistanceView(foundBeacon);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                beaconManager.startRanging(region);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        beaconManager.stopRanging(region);
        beaconManager.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

I hope it will Help you that to get the function for detecting the Beaconlist.:)